# How to use share plugin in flutter

Tags: flutter

i want to add a share options to my flutter app to share articles to another place  like this image below :[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqLAx.jpg)

i did read the documentation of https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share 
and i installed the dependencies of share plugin but i couldn't apply it to my code because it not clear how must use it , please give me an example to how can i apply it .

my code :

```
body: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(

                child: Image.network(widget.post.data["image_url"],height: 400.0,width: 500.0),
              ),
              **/// i want to apply it exactly here  in this line** 
              Expanded(
                child: ListTile(


                  //leading: Image.network(widget.post.data["image_url"]),
                  title: Text(widget.post.data["title"],
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 17.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  subtitle: Text(widget.post.data["content"],
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the examples of any first party Flutter package in their repositories: [Share plugin example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/share/example/lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how you can use `share` plugin. Let's say you have a button titled `share`, clicking on it will open the default apps on device using which you share an article, link, picture or a document etc. Code :

```
Container(
         child: RaisedButton(
         onPressed: () => Share.share(// add your link or image here),
         child:Text('Share'),
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 
         BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
         ),
```

Comment: you mean that if i have an article that i want to share it must replace it in Share,share() between the brackets ??

Comment: Whatever you want to share goes inside Share.share() method. Also check the github example shared in above answer as well. These should be enough to solve your question.